# What is the difference of envfit vegan result using scores function and extract the vectors?

Tags: r, vegan

What is the difference among the vectors (fit$vectors) obtained from envfit function of vegan (R package) and extract it using (scores function):

```
library(vegan)
data(varespec, varechem)
ord <- metaMDS(varespec)
fit <- envfit(ord, varechem, perm = 999)

fit$vectors
            NMDS1    NMDS2     r2 Pr(>r)    
N        -0.05699 -0.99837 0.2538  0.044 *  
P         0.61934  0.78513 0.1938  0.116    
K         0.76606  0.64277 0.1809  0.124    
Ca        0.68482  0.72871 0.4119  0.006 ** 
Mg        0.63219  0.77481 0.4271  0.003 ** 
S         0.19092  0.98161 0.1752  0.115    
Al       -0.87184  0.48978 0.5269  0.001 ***
Fe       -0.93628  0.35126 0.4450  0.005 ** 
Mn        0.79879 -0.60162 0.5230  0.001 ***
Zn        0.61731  0.78672 0.1879  0.121    
Mo       -0.90312  0.42938 0.0609  0.515    
Baresoil  0.92521 -0.37947 0.2508  0.052 .  
Humdepth  0.93300 -0.35987 0.5199  0.002 ** 
pH       -0.64823  0.76144 0.2307  0.070 .  
---
Signif. codes:  0 ‘***’ 0.001 ‘**’ 0.01 ‘*’ 0.05 ‘.’ 0.1 ‘ ’ 1
Permutation: free
Number of permutations: 999
```

or

```
data.frame(scores(fit, "vectors"))
               NMDS1      NMDS2
N        -0.02871183 -0.5029777
P         0.27264080  0.3456235
K         0.32580371  0.2733667
Ca        0.43952421  0.4676897
Mg        0.41315337  0.5063630
S         0.07992162  0.4109201
Al       -0.63286315  0.3555304
Fe       -0.62458948  0.2343268
Mn        0.57765907 -0.4350718
Zn        0.26758332  0.3410181
Mo       -0.22295444  0.1060014
Baresoil  0.46331553 -0.1900256
Humdepth  0.67275508 -0.2594927
pH       -0.31134547  0.3657210
```

why each NMDS columns have different values, which of them are the best to plot the significant (<0.05) variables against sites ???

```
sites <- data.frame(ord$points)
```

scores function

```
sc <- data.frame(scores(fit, "vectors"))
```

or

```
sc <- data.frame(fit$vectors) 


ggplot(data=sites, aes(x=MDS1, y=MDS2)) + geom_point() + coord_fixed() +
    geom_segment(data = sc, aes(x = 0, xend = NMDS1, y = 0, yend = NMDS2),
                 arrow = arrow(length = unit(0.25, "cm")), colour = "grey") +
    geom_text(data = sc, aes(x = NMDS1, y = NMDS2, label = rownames(sc)),
              size = 3)
```

using scores function or using fit$vectors  ???

Thanks so much

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to the documentation (see `?envfit`) "The printed output of continuous variables (vectors) gives the direction cosines which are the coordinates of the heads of unit length vectors." Further it explains that "In `plot` these are scaled by their correlation (square root of the column ‘r2’) so that “weak” predictors have shorter arrows than “strong” predictors.  You can see the scaled relative lengths using command `scores`." The last piece of information is confirmed at the end of the documentation which says "The results can be accessed with `scores.envfit` function which returns ... the fitted vectors scaled by correlation coefficient". So the difference is correlation, and you should use the results extracted by `scores`. The directly accessed direction cosines will draw unit-length arrows (like you should see) irrespective of the strength of the variable.

The conventional `plot` function in **vegan** can select variables by permutation *P*-values, but `geom_text` and `geom_segment` have no idea of doing this. You should only pass those rows that you want to plot, and remove the other scores.